# Background image changer by time

Tags: javascript, html, background

I need some suggestions and ideas to improve a background image rotator.

Thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = ['bg1.png', 'bg2.png', 'bg3.png'];
    var curImage = 0;
    function switchImage()
    {
        curImage = (curImage + 1) % images.length
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[curImage] + ')'
    }
    window.setInterval(switchImage, 500);
</script>
```

1. I want the images to fade into each other.
2. I need to be able to preload the images so it doesn't have the delay when loading them when they first display.

Answer (score 0):

preloading images is done with the Image object and its source, as in...

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "mypicture.jpg";
```

that will preload them.

As for fading, you'll want to create an animation using the alpha property of the css of the container div.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Just increment/decrement the opacity over time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Preloading:

```
var images = ['bg1.png', 'bg2.png', 'bg3.png'];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    (new Image()).src = window.location.href + '/images/' + images[i]; 
}
```

Change this part `window.location.href + '/images/'` to suit you better.

2) Fading

In short you cannot fade background images.

If you absolutely ***need*** fading, you'll have to create your backgrounds in an `img` tag, and position it behind the content of your `body`, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XH78L/

Comment: i have seen background images fading already in many web 2.0 sites so it is possible

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var displayBox;

$(document).ready(function() {

  StartShow();

});

function StartShow() {
    var interval = 5000;
    var slideShowID;

    slideShowID = setInterval(Gallery, interval);

}

function Gallery() {
  var nextImage = $("#container li.selected").next().length;
  if (nextImage > 0){
    $("#container li.selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
    imgSrc = $("#container li.selected").children().attr("src");
    if(imgSrc != null) {
      $("#banner").fadeOut('slow', function() { $("#banner").css("background-image", imgSrc); }).fadeIn();
    }
  }
  else {
    $("#container li.selected").removeClass("selected").siblings(':first').addClass("selected");
    imgSrc = $("#container li.selected").children().attr("src");
    if (imgSrc != null) {
      $("#banner").fadeOut('slow', function() { $("#banner").css("background-image", imgSrc); }).fadeIn();
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="container" style="display: none;">
    <li class="thumbnail selected"><img src="1.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="2.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="3.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="4.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="5.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="6.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="7.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="8.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="thumbnail"><img src="9.jpg"/></li>
</ul>


<div id="banner"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just set the starting background-image to whatever image you want to load on land and then the show will start on Document.Ready.